# multiple @ComponentScan in Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-4

I am using Spring 4.16 with Java Annotations, and i want to do something like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.business", includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ServiceComponent.class))
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.business.framework")
public class ServicesBaseConfiguration {

}
```

Obviusly, it doesn't compile. But i hope you get my point. I want to have multiple ComponentScans with differents packages and filters.

I cannot unify both ComponentsScan because it wouldn't create any component from framework but those which are annotated with ServiceComponent, am i right?

Do you know how could i solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create two empty internal classes and put the `@ComponentScan` annotation on them:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ServicesBaseConfiguration.Filtered.class, ServicesBaseConfiguration.Unfiltered.class})
public class ServicesBaseConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.business", includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ServiceComponent.class))
    public static class Filtered {}

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.business.framework")
    public static class Unfiltered {}

}
```

That should work

Comment: Although this works, I would consider this a workaround. I took the liberty to create an enhancement request for this. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13151

Comment: Thanks to you both! I accept your answer since apparently is the only way to do this... Regards!

Comment: Good job to @M.Deinum ! The feature has been implemented and I our team is using it happily :)